# Swift Framework Added via Cocoapods into Objective-C App - "Module not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift3, xcode8

In Xcode 8 I'm having trouble importing any Swift 2.3 or 3 framework that was added with Cocoapods into my project.

There is a public umbrella.h file, but for some reason Xcode can't find the framework when I try to @import it.

As an example, create any Objective-C project, use the following Podfile, pod install, and then try the `@import`. It asks me to update the code to swift 2.3 or 3 even if that code is already Swift 2.3 or Swift 3 code. I've cleaned and tried to rebuild as well.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'testingFrameworks' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

Did I miss a step?

Comment: You called `pod install` after you modified the `Podfile`, right?

Answer (score 1):

I used socketIO and was having the same problem. My solution to this is:

1. Close project.
2. Delete pod files, delivered files, pod framework, workspace file (clean up project)
3. pod install
4. Reopen workspace, upgrade swift syntax if xcode ask for, build a few times.

You might need to fix something for the new swift.

Comment: This was in a new project with Swift 3 code. Even if no Swift 3 upgrades need to happen the Framework added with Cocoapods into my Obj-C project is not found when using @import FrameworkName;

Comment: oh, so your main project is using swift? Mine use Objective-C and I don't know much about swift, so pardon me. But probably the problem is with the building system :/

Comment: No, sorry. My main project or any new Objective-C project is having this error. I just tried a new Objective-C project with SocketIO's Swift3 version. Everything upgrades but the module still cannot be found.

https://s14.postimg.io/qxee39a6p/Socket_IOModule_Missing.png

Comment: 'Defines Module' is set to yes for both can sometimes remove the error but it returns.

Comment: But have you tried my solution? Anw, it seems like a very common issue for xcode 8

Comment: Alright, I just remembered that I've updated pod repo to the newest (using git, not pod command). Maybe that'll help?

Comment: Yes, it did not solve the problem.

Try starting a new test Objective-C iOS app and create a new Podfile with Socket IO's master (Swift 3/Xcode 8) compatible version. It will have you upgrade to Swift 3, then after setting your target to 'Defines Module = yes', your controller will still be unable to find '@import SocketIO'. This is definitely a bug even after clearing derived data/clean/rebuilding.